# how to change line colors in primefaces 5.1 line chart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, jqplot

I'm using primefaces 5.1 and tried to create line chart,its working fine.
But i want to customize the background color ,grids, line colors.

My XHTML:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartViewLine.lineModel1}" style="height:300px; width:570px;"/>
```

My JAVA file:

```
private LineChartModel lineModel1;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createLineModels();
}

public LineChartModel getLineModel1() {
    return lineModel1;
}

private void createLineModels() {
    lineModel1 = initLinearModel();
    lineModel1.setLegendCols(3);
    lineModel1.setLegendPosition("e");
    Axis yAxis = lineModel1.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(10);

   }

private LineChartModel initLinearModel() {
    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();

    LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
    series1.setLabel("Series 1");

    series1.set(1, 2);
    series1.set(2, 1);
    series1.set(3, 3);

    LineChartSeries series2 = new LineChartSeries();
    series2.setLabel("Series 2");

    series2.set(1, 6);
    series2.set(2, 3);
    series2.set(3, 2);

    model.addSeries(series1);
    model.addSeries(series2);
    return model;
}
```

The above code working fine but I need to change the UI. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

i suggest reading [jqplot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/multipleBarColors.html)

java code

```
lineModel.setSeriesColors("58BA27,FFCC33,F74A4A,F52F2F,A30303");
lineModel.setExtender("chartExtender");
```